# Using circular buffers inside a TF(2.0) model

Tags: python, tensorflow, circular-buffer

I'm looking for a way to optimize my tensorflow (2.0) UNet model for streaming data. The goal is to store activations of previous **predictions** in circular buffers, in order to reuse part of the buffers in next predictions.

I've found the following TensorFlow op [FIFOQueue](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/queue/FIFOQueue?version=stable) and conceptually, this is in the right direction. However, it only seems to be used in the context of data loading. I could not find any good leads in the `.layers` documentation.

Can this be tackled with the Tensorflow API? Would this problem be sufficiently low-level to break the barrier into the C++ API? Currently I'm developing in Python.